# Xamarin iOS change colour of some map pins

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Xamarin Forms application which implements a custom map renderer for Android and iOS. I would like to implement custom pins, where different colours mean different things on my map.

My code for adding pins to my custom map is here:

```
 List<BasicMapAnnotation> annotationList = new List<BasicMapAnnotation>();

 for (int i = 0; i < userLocations.Count; i++)
 {
      LatLong latLongs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatLong>(userLocations[i].coords);
      var annotation = new BasicMapAnnotation(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.latitude), Convert.ToDouble(latLongs.longitude)), userLocations[i].user_id, "Latitude: " + latLongs.latitude.ToString() + " Longitude: " + latLongs.longitude.ToString());

      annotationList.Add(annotation);
 }
 nativeMap.AddAnnotations(annotationList.ToArray());
```

How do I now add some custom login when drawing my pins, such that they are different colours?

```
if(something())
{
  annotation.colour = Color.Green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that on iOS you can set the PinTintColor but on Android you have to set a bitmap for the pin.

Have a look at the [source code for TK.Custom map on GitHub](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/tree/master)  in particular the custom renderers. They show how to change the color of the pins.

Here is code from the iOS custom renderer showing changing a pin color.

```
var pinAnnotationView = annotationView as MKPinAnnotationView;
if (pinAnnotationView != null)
{
    pinAnnotationView.AnimatesDrop = AnimateOnPinDrop;

    var pinTintColorAvailable = pinAnnotationView.RespondsToSelector(new Selector("pinTintColor"));

    if (!pinTintColorAvailable)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (pin.DefaultPinColor != Color.Default)
    {
        pinAnnotationView.PinTintColor = pin.DefaultPinColor.ToUIColor();
    }
    else
    {
        pinAnnotationView.PinTintColor = UIColor.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should be able to use something like annotation.PinTintColor? Because I don't think annotations have such a function unfortunately

Comment: I added code to my answer showing changing the pin color on iOS - taken from TK.CustomMap iOS renderer

Comment: Thanks for that Steve, when is this code called in a custom map renderer?

Comment: You are best off having a look at the custom renderer via the link in my answer. There is a lot in there.I wrote my own custom map renderers based on it but did not implement pin colors.